# Understanding space allocation for variables on stack

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, stack

I want to understand how space allocation is done for variables on stack.

Here for this C program with no variables

```
main() { return 0; }
```

It's disassembly is

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 0c0h      


main() {
int i = 10; }
```

The dis-assembly for this program is

```
push ebp 
mov ebp, esp 
sub esp, 0cch
```

I am initializing an INT variable, whose size is 4 bytes. But in the above dis-assembly compiler is allocating 12 bytes (0cc-0c0).

For the following program

```
main() { long long int i = 10LL; }
```

The disassembly is

```
push ebp 
mov ebp, esp 
sub esp, 0D0h
```

In the above disassembly compiler is allocating 16 bytes(0D0 - 0C0) for long long int, whose size is 8 bytes.

Why is compiler assigning 12 bytes(4 bytes extra allocated. It should be 8 byte or 16 byte aligned) for INT, whose size is 4 bytes and 16 bytes for LONG LONG INT, whose size is 8 bytes?

Can someone please clarify this.

Thanks.

Comment: asked about a zillion times on this site...

Comment: @dwelch That's not helfpful unless you actually provide a link.

Comment: too many links, the OP didnt bother to look, should look first.

Comment: @dwelch I just tried to do a search and couldn't find anything that explained why the compiler is allocating extra space. Not saying the question doesn't exist, but it's not that easy to find either. I will admit that there are a number of them showing up as related on the side.

Comment: Google "stack frames" for the given OS.

Comment: One thing I recommend is not reviewing debug builds. I assume this is a debug build with incremental linking on (and/or edit and continue). As long as data is aligned on the stack appropriately it doesn't matter how much space is allocated (as long as the stack remains on a 4-byte boundary before a function call). As long as the data is placed into the local stack space at proper alignments the size of the space allocated doesn't much matter. In your case you have incremental linking on so stack space is reserved via internal MSVC logic to handle that.

Comment: If you review a release build (which generally isn't compiled for incremental building) you might get a better idea of how the stack is allocated without the fluff.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is free to allocate as much extra storage as it wants. The C standard does not dictate constraints on the stack allocation.

EDIT:

I did some experimentation on [godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org) with the ICC compiler, the only compiler that generates code like your example. I disproved myself about the arguments to main thing I mentioned before. I also tried creating some character arrays and found that the stack will always allocate in increments of 16 bytes. A char array of 1-16 bytes all cause a 16-byte allocation. Next 17-32 will cause a 32-byte allocation and so on.